# Simple IIS 7 Rewrite rule not working

Tags: iis, redirect, iis-7, url-rewriting

I've seen several blogs and questions which I believe match what I'm doing, but it's not working.  URL Rewrite module is installed.  I'm resetting IIS after I save this web.config file.  I've tried using IIS's GUI as well with same results.  Is there something else I'm not aware of?

```
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.us$" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.us/{R:0}" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I forgot to add the binding domain.us to the site.  Woops!